# 301 Redirect where 2 domains point to same IP?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have 2 TLDs `example.com` and `example.ie`.

`example.com` and `example.ie` both point at the same IP address and pull the same content now we could get whacked with a ban hammer from Google for duplicate content so we want anyone accessing `*.example.ie` and `*.example.com` to be redirected to `www.example.com` the problem is as they are both pointing at the same server the .htaccess is the same thus I don't believe we can do the usual:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

So how do we go about creating a search-engine friendly 301 redirect from `*.example.ie` and `*.example.com` to `www.example.com`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

That will redirect (statuscode 301 "permantly moved") every domain which is **not** www.example.com to www.example.com.

Comment: This looks fine to me, have an upvote! :) Maybe you should add the QSA flag, though.

Comment: No need for QSA here. It gets already appended. So if you open example.com/index.php?site=123 you will get redirected to www.example.com/index.php?site=123 .. or am I missing sth?

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer what I used in the end was:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule (.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]`

Comment: @Myles Gray: you should escape dots in regexp like \. in your RewriteCond

Answer (score 0):

The 301 redirect you posted is just fine; the HTTP header of every request (nowadays) contains the name of the host.

As an alternative, you can use [`rel=canonical`](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/canonical-link-tag/). It's not that urgent anyway, as duplicate content on just two domains is [unlikely to be a problem](https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dgk2ft62_40g8w32thb).

Comment: Changed question slightly - we need `*.example.com` and `*.example.ie` to redirect to `www.example.com` but I fear recursion there... being that `*.example.com` encapsulates `www.example.com`?

Comment: @Myles Gray: Well, make an exception for `www.example.com` to not redirect.